# Mudar contexto para receber informações do banco de dados

Tags: c#, asp.net

Eu peguei um projeto de um filemanager, que usa handler e o mesmo usa exemplos listando os diretorios e arquivos do proprio projeto, coloquei um exemplo listando diretorio que já funciona, porém não consigo fazer o mesmo para arquivo:

```
namespace Filemanager
{
/// <summary>
/// Summary description for FilemanagerHandler
/// </summary>
public class FilemanagerHandler : IHttpHandler
{

    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        try
        {
            var opName = context.Request.Params["opName"];
            List<FileItem> retList = new List<FileItem>();
            short i;
            switch (opName)
            {
                case "getDirs":
                    var dir = context.Request.QueryString["dir"];
                    //lista diretorios Raiz
                    var listaDir = DiretorioController.getAllDirectory("");
                    foreach (var diretorio in listaDir)
                    {
                        retList.Add(new FileItem(diretorio.nomeDiretorio));
                    }
                    break;
                case "getFiles":
                    dir = context.Request.QueryString["dir"];
                    foreach (var address in Directory.GetFiles(context.Server.MapPath(dir)))
                    {
                        retList.Add(new FileItem(address));
                    }
                    break;
                case "uplaodFile":
                    dir = context.Request.Params["dir"];
                    //HttpPostedFile file = context.Request.Files["fileUpload"];
                    foreach (string key in context.Request.Files.AllKeys)
                    {
                        HttpPostedFile file = context.Request.Files[key];
                        if (file != null && file.ContentLength > 0)
                        {
                            string fileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
                            string address = context.Server.MapPath(Path.Combine(dir, fileName));
                            i = 1;
                            while (File.Exists(address))
                            {
                                address = context.Server.MapPath(Path.Combine(dir, Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fileName) + " (" + i++ + ")" + Path.GetExtension(fileName)));
                            }
                            file.SaveAs(address);
                        }
                    }
                    break;
                case "addFolder":
                    dir = context.Request.Params["dir"];
                    Directory.CreateDirectory(context.Server.MapPath(Path.Combine(dir, context.Request.Params["folderName"].ToString())));
                    context.Response.Redirect(context.Request.UrlReferrer.ToString());
                    break;
                case "addFile":
                    dir = context.Request.Params["dir"];
                    var filename = context.Request.Params["fileName"].ToString();
                    filename = string.IsNullOrEmpty(Path.GetExtension(filename)) ? filename + ".txt" : filename;
                    StreamWriter streamWriter = File.CreateText(context.Server.MapPath(Path.Combine(dir, filename)));
                    streamWriter.Close();
                    break;
                case "dlFile":
                    dir = context.Request.Params["dir"];
                    context.Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
                    filename = context.Server.MapPath(dir);
                    context.Response.WriteFile(filename);
                    context.Response.Headers.Add("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=" + Path.GetFileName(filename));
                    return;
                    break;
                case "copy":
                    var dir1 = context.Request.Params["dir1"];
                    var dir2 = context.Request.Params["dir2"];
                    var addressTocopy = context.Server.MapPath(Path.Combine(dir1, Path.GetFileName(dir2)));
                    i = 1;
                    while (File.Exists(addressTocopy))
                    {
                        addressTocopy =
                            context.Server.MapPath(Path.Combine(dir1,
                                                                Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(dir2) + " (" +
                                                                i + ")" + Path.GetExtension(dir2)));
                    }
                    File.Copy(context.Server.MapPath(dir2), addressTocopy);
                    break;
                case "cut":
                    dir1 = context.Request.Params["dir1"];
                    dir2 = context.Request.Params["dir2"];
                    addressTocopy = context.Server.MapPath(Path.Combine(dir1, Path.GetFileName(dir2)));
                    i = 1;
                    while (File.Exists(addressTocopy))
                    {
                        addressTocopy =
                            context.Server.MapPath(Path.Combine(dir1,
                                                                Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(dir2) + " (" +
                                                                i + ")" + Path.GetExtension(dir2)));
                    }
                    File.Move(context.Server.MapPath(dir2), addressTocopy);
                    break;
                case "delete":
                    dir = context.Request.Params["dir"];
                    string deleteAdd = context.Server.MapPath(dir);
                    if (File.Exists(deleteAdd))
                    {
                        File.Delete(deleteAdd);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if (Directory.Exists(deleteAdd))
                            Directory.Delete(deleteAdd);
                    }
                    break;
                case "rename":
                    dir = context.Server.MapPath(context.Request.Params["dir"]);
                    var rename = context.Request.Params["name"];
                    if (File.Exists(dir))
                    {
                        var renameAdd = string.IsNullOrEmpty(Path.GetExtension(rename))
                                            ? Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(dir),
                                                           rename + Path.GetExtension(dir))
                                            : Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(dir), rename);
                        File.Move(dir, renameAdd);
                        retList.Add(new FileItem(renameAdd));
                    }
                    else if (Directory.Exists(dir))
                    {
                        var renameAdd = Path.Combine(dir.Remove(dir.LastIndexOf('\\') + 1), rename);
                        Directory.Move(dir, renameAdd);
                        retList.Add(new FileItem(renameAdd));
                    }
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
            if (context.Request.Headers["X-Requested-With"] == "XMLHttpRequest")
                context.Response.Write(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(retList));
            else
                context.Response.Redirect(context.Request.UrlReferrer.ToString());
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

        }
    }

    public bool IsReusable
    {
        get
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

}

Classe ListItem:

```
namespace Filemanager.Classes
{
public class FileItem
{
    private string _address;

    private FileInfo fileInfo;

    public string Title { get { return Address.ToCharArray().Contains('/') ? Address.Remove(0, Address.LastIndexOf('/')).TrimStart('/') : Address; } }

    public FileItem(string address)
    {
        _address = address;
        fileInfo = new FileInfo(_address);
    }

    public string Address
    {
        get { return _address.Replace(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("/"), "").Replace("\\", "/"); }
        set { _address = value; }
    }

    public string Extension
    {
        get
        {
            try
            {
                var ext = Path.GetExtension(Address);
                return string.IsNullOrEmpty(ext) ? "folder" : ext.TrimStart('.');
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                return "";
            }
        }
    }

    public string Category { get { return GetCategory(Extension); } }

    public long FileSize { get { return Category.ToLower() == "folder" ? 0 : fileInfo.Length; } }

    public DateTime DateCreated { get { return fileInfo.CreationTime; } }

    protected string GetCategory(string extension)
    {
        string[] imageTypes = { ".jpg", ".jpeg", ".png", ".bmp", ".tiff", ".gif" };
        string[] programTypes = { ".html", ".cs", ".js", ".css", ".aspx", ".ashx", ".config" };
        if (Extension.Equals("folder", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(Extension))
        {
            return "Folder";
        }
        else if (imageTypes.Contains(extension.ToLower()))
        {
            return "Image";
        }
        else if (programTypes.Contains(extension.ToLowerInvariant()))
        {
            return "Code";
        }
        return "Unknown";
    }
}
```

}
Porem ai trabalha com diretorios locais, o que tenho que mudar tanto para listar de meu banco de dados? já tenho todos os métodos dal prontos e funcionando.

Referencia do projeto: https://github.com/danielrajaei/Filemanager/tree/master/Filemanager

Comment: Qual a tecnologia de acesso ao seu banco de dados? Poderia dar um exemplo de seleção simples na sua pergunta?

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez é entity framework, eu tenho um metodo que retorna uma lista de diretorios, troquei o foreach la pelo meu da lista, e listou os diretorios, porem fui fazer o mesmo nos arquivos e não foi. da arquivo não encontrado. é como se a classe FileItem fosse estática pra um diretorio de arquivos. Editei a pergunta com o exemplo do método da minha seleção.

Comment: Qual o erro que você tem com o `FileItem`? Aparentemente o problema que você tem é diferente da ideia geral da pergunta.

Comment: Não não consegui adaptar nada ainda,se eu colocar o mesmo foreach que fiz em diretorios, trocando pelo meu metodo de arquivos la em case:"getFiles" aparece: Não foi possível localizar o arquivo 'Chrysanthemum.jpg'. esse arquivo é um dos dados cadastrados no bd, esse erro é porque a classe FileItem está puxando um local estatico?tenho que setar la para a pasta onde vai ficar salvo os arquivos? estou em duvida do contexto, não quero que façam tudo esses metodos ai, apenas queria deixar a listagem de diretorios/arquivos funcionando.

Comment: Acho que é um problema na construção do Path. Aparentemente está usando um caminho relativo. Experimente fazer um teste usando `Path.Join` e `Server.MapPath`. Se for preciso, coloco uma resposta pra você usando esses dois recursos.

Comment: Não entendi, tenho que colocar isso aonde?

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no bate-papo](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/21374/discussion-between-war-lock-and-cigano-morrison-mendez).

Comment: Estranho que apenas com meu metodo de obter arquivos ele da erro, eu repeti no mesmo local meu metodo de obter diretorios, e lista normalmente,ambos retornam nomes(string).Não entendo porque o de arquivos ele da erro.

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez vai chat pf.